# Continuing number of pages from previous section

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document split into 3 sections. Section 1 is the cover page with no numbers, section 2 is the contents with numerals, and section 3 is the main body (portrait), in the footer I have Page X of Y where X is the page number and Y is the total number of pages in the section (SectionPages). I now want to add an Appendix where the pages are Landscape so created a new section, I can continue the page numbers from the previous section but how can I continue the number of pages from the previous section?

Comment: Normally you might choose a1, a2 instead

Answer (score 1):

There is no really simple way to do it, but you can do this.

Put this set of field codes somewhere in all your footers

```
{ SET "SECP{ SECTION }" { SECTIONPAGES } }
```

(*all* the {  } have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert on the Windows Desktop verion of Word using ctrl-F9. You can use alt-F9 to toggle between "field code" view and "field results" view.)

That means that the bookmark SECP1 will be set tot he number of pages in section 1, SECP2 to the number of pages in section 2, and so on.

So in Section 4 (your Appendix section) you can insert the following field codes to display the number of pages in section 3+section 4

```
{ =SECP3+SECP4 }
```

If, for example, you know that you want to add the section page counts of the last two sections regardless of how many section there are, you can use

```
{ ={ "SECP{ ={ SECTION }-1 }" }+{ "SECP{ SECTION }" } }
```

Notes.

This may break down if you have any continuous section breaks, because the same page may be counted twice.

You *can* use a shorter bookmark name if you want, e.g. use

```
{ SET "S{ SECTION }" { SECTIONPAGES } }
```

but then you will find that

```
{ =S1+S2 }
```

doesn't work. It's because bookmarks whose structure looks like Word table cell names (A1, A2 etc.) confuse Word. But the following nested fields should work:

```
{ ={ S1 }+{ S2 } }
```

NB, if you use "S" instead of a longer string such as "SECP" then that won't work because the bookmark names S1 and S2 look like table cell